# What is this seafood that I bought in a Chinese market?

Tags: food-identification, chinese-cuisine, seafood

Can someone tell what is the food here?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's [abalone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abalone) (鮑魚 *bàoyú*), a popular and expensive delicacy in Chinese cuisine.

Comment: And there are many different ways of preparing it, including steamed or pan fried. It’s also used in Japanese cuisine (including sushi), as well as in regional French cuisine (it’s called ormeaux in French), though it’s heavily regulated in France.